# WPF Combo binding to datatable: Strange behaviour

Tags: wpf, binding, combobox, character

I've a strange problem when trying to bind a WPF combo to a set of column values in a datatable. The binding works fine, but the values in the combo are the individual characters in the first item of the column and not the whole string. (I cannot post image and so uploaded it to the following location)

http://tinypic.com/r/293hx0o/7

My combo is a simple one with no templates and is in a grid with a label in first column and this combo in second column :

```
 <ComboBox IsTextSearchEnabled="True" IsEditable="True" Name="cbIDef" BorderThickness="1"  Height="28"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" BorderBrush="Black" FontSize="15" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Name}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" SelectedValuePath="Name" />
```

My code behind:

```
 Dim lobjDT As New DataTable("TestTable")
 lobjDT.Columns.Add("Poem")
 lobjDT.Columns.Add("Line1")
 lobjDT.Columns.Add("Line2")

 Dim lobjNewRow As DataRow = lobjDT.NewRow

 With lobjNewRow
     .Item(0) = "Baba Black Sheep"
     .Item(1) = "Have you any wool"
     .Item(2) = "Yes sir Yes sir"
 End With

 lobjDT.Rows.Add(lobjNewRow)
 <Some Nested CLR object>.cbIDef.DataContext = lobjDT
```

Can someone please enlighten me where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your binding path as follows

="{DisplayMemberPath =Poem}"

You can see an example at http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFSelectedValue.aspx

Comment: I removed the Path from ItemsSource and then it worked perfectly well. Now it is ItemsSource="{Binding}". Thanks alot.